# Mac / Unix: overwritten path variable

Tags: macos, unix, path, terminal

I was starting to type the command `export PATH=/newPathAddition:$PATH` I think I must have copied in a newline when copying the `newPathAddition` to paste into the command, because it ran `export PATH=/newPathAddition`.  I know I can manually add things to the path variable, but is there any way to restore it to what it used to be, or find out information about which directories were in the path beforehand?  I really don't want to be in a situation in the future where all these commands aren't working on my computer because things vanished from the path that I don't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These changes are local to this one command prompt. Just open another terminal window.

If you need the normal value of `$PATH` to use in this one specific terminal window, open another one and copy its `$PATH` value.

If you want changes to `$PATH` to persist, you need to write a `.bashrc` file or a `.profile` file in your home folder with the `$PATH`-altering commands you wish to use. To revert, take them out.